# Nginx: / for both static content and proxied application

Tags: nginx, web-server, web-applications, static-content, static-files

- `http://example.com`: my site
- `http://example.net`: the proxied backend

I'm trying to setup an nginx server block as both a static content server and a reverse proxy. Nginx should first check for static files and then redirect to the proxied application if no file exists. It is configured as such:

```
location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://example.net;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}
```

However, with such a configuration accessing `http://example.com` returns a `403 Forbidden`: it seems that nginx tries to serve a static folder, does not find an `index.html` and fails without proxying `example.net`. I then have to explicitly add a route for `/`:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://example.net;
}
```

That way `http://example.com/` is properly proxied to `http://example.net`. But such a configuration feels odd: is there a better way to proxy `/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$uri/` clause is causing the problem.

If you do not need a trailing `/` to be added to URIs that represent a static directory, you could use:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
}
```

Alternatively, your existing solution also works with a `try_files` instead of a duplicate `proxy_pass`:

```
location = / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.